# Inbox dropdown height too small and requires too much scrolling

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, design

Currently when I open the global inbox drop-down is occupies less that half of available browser window height and so provides a very narrow window that requires lots of scrolling.

[image]

Could you please make it adaptive to the browser window height and make it occupy something like two thirds of the browser window height?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it yourself by changing the `width`  property of  `div#seWrapper` and the `height` property of `#seWrapper .seContainer`.

I'm sure there's a lot of add-ons that can already do that for every browser out there.